# Navigate one screen to other in PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I want to navigate from one screen to other when i click the button.

I have few question regarding the application:

1. Is it neccessary to create the .js file for every html file?
2. Do we need to create only html or can able to make the application by creating only .js file?
3. Is it possible to navigate from one screen to other by writing some javascript code in .html file?

Comment: It's Phonegap not iphonegap.

Comment: @Vin: it's PhoneGap, not Phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

**1)Is it neccessary to create the .js file for every html file?**

**ans 1** Its not necessary if you have the same functions for the rest of the pages. I have never tried it ..but logically it is correct.

**2)Is it neccessary to create the html or can we run the application by creating only .js file?**

**ans 2** You have not understood the PhoneGap working concept... Your **HTML and CSS** is for the **designing** your application and your **javascript /Jquery** is for adding **functionality**

**3)How should I navigate from one screen to other?**

**ans 3** that you can do it like this..

```
 <div id="xyz" class="your CSS"><img src="img/abc.png" onClick="test()"/></div>

 function test()
 {
     window.location.href="index.html";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.it is very usefule.I had created new HTML file. and tries to navigate to that file by using :- window.location.href="test.html";  but it doesnot work

Comment: It is giving me this error:- Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @shweta, i suppose..you would have committed a mistake in the path of the file... . update your code or fiddle it...only then I can help you

Comment: @shweta,could you fix this?

Comment: yes i understand the 3 question..But i still not able to navigate from one user to another by window.open